# quantmod: Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401

Tags: r, quantmod

library(quantmod)
getQuote("AAPL")

I don't understand why I suddenly get an error message:

Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401.

Thanks for any help!

Georg

I just wanted a real time quote on apple but it looks like there is a problem!

Comment: Duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/q/76058920/271616