# In the R library quantmod, is there a new problem with getQuote?

Tags: r, quantmod

I've been using `getQuote` from the `quantmod` package for a while.  In the past few days, its begun failing with an HTTP error message:

```
     library(quantmod)
     getQuote("MSFT")
```

which returns "Error in open.connection(con, "rb") : HTTP error 401."

Has something stopped working?

Comment: Yes, please see https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/382

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This was an issue with the Yahoo Finance servers. It went away after a few days. See https://github.com/joshuaulrich/quantmod/issues/382 for details.

Answer (score -1):

There was an issue with Yahoo API. Do this.

## if you have already loaded the package.

detach("package:quantmod", unload = TRUE)
remotes::install_github("ethanbsmith/quantmod@382_add_session_getQuote")